# jekyll GitHub Page page not loading assets

Tags: jekyll, assets, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I have a GitHub hosted  https://waltershub.github.io the repo is https://github.com/waltershub/waltershub.github.io

The site builds properly locally with all assets and css but on the hosted version none of it shows

The errors in console are:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (HTTP/2.0 404) (font-awesome.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (HTTP/2.0 404) (dark.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (HTTP/2.0 404) (function.js, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (HTTP/2.0 404) (walt.jpg, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (HTTP/2.0 404) (walt.jpg, line 0)
```

I have validated the YAML and it is good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `_config.yml` you are using a baseurl of `webpage`:

```yml
baseurl: "/webpage" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
```

When according to your setup should be `''`:

```yml
baseurl: ""
```

Then the part that load assets:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{site.baseurl}}/assets/stylesheets/{% if site.blog_theme == "light" %}light.css{% else %}dark.css{% endif %}">
```

Will properly generate the urls like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/stylesheets/dark.css">
```

Tnstead of the wrong:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webpage/assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webpage/assets/stylesheets/dark.css">
```